How cost efficient are older jets versus buying a newer jet?
I notice that older private jets are a lot cheaper than newer ones. For example, 2019 Falcon 2000LXS might cost say \$24 million but a 2015 may only cost \$20 million and a new LXS costs \$35 million. Is this price difference new car smell, or are there significant reasons why a newer one is worth so much more?
I ask because I know with smaller aircraft I have flow like Cessna 172s and things like that, the differences between a 1990 and 1970 are more or less trivial (or at least I think they are), so for a smaller aircraft I would definitely buy an older aircraft and save a LOT of money. However, I am wondering if this same logic scales up to jets?
I suspect that it does because I know that a fractional ownership group that I do business with has a policy of always buying only new jets and always selling them as soon as they are 5 years old. I asked them the reason for this policy and did not get any kind of convincing answer, so I got the impression that the policy is purely psychological in that the clients want to fly a "new" aircraft and there seemed to be no practical reason for it. So, if this is the situation that most jet owners (like car owners) dump their jets just because they are "old", then it would seem to make financial sense to only buy older jets. Is this right?

The older an airframe, the more time per year it will spend in maintenance, being unavailable to its customers or in this case fractional-owners. Frequent flying also increases maintenance hours per year. An older jet, flown frequently, will spend the most time getting serviced and thus unavailable.
The depreciation is even worse with airliners - they can drop 10-fold in 10 years, due to the wear and high cost of D-checks. Buying a used jet is like buying a company: you get both the debts and the assets, the debts being wear and maintenance intervals.
Private jets get far fewer flight hours per year than commercial ones, and are subject to less regulation. Trump famously owns a refurbished 757 that was all but written off - private jet service makes a good second life for worn commercial jets.
Fractional ownership is more akin to a charter service than to a true private jet, which won't fly much more often than its owner. These jets get considerable mileage, and will require maintenance. Ideally, you'd want to use up the flight-hours and the years on each part about equally over the life of the airframe. It makes both technical and commercial sense to run a jet hard for 5 years, then sell it off to a private owner, while many parts still have plenty of hours left that might last them a lifetime.
Low-cost carriers, which drive their jets the hardest, also often have a policy of flying only new airplanes. This way, they get the highest availability and predictability, which are important for their schedules. It's also possible, not necessarily for this company, that the jets are leased rather than bought, in which case these years would be a hard limit.
Short version: Older jets are cheaper per airframe. Newer jets are cheaper per flight hour. So you buy new to fly, old to own.

On complex airplanes like jets, it's fairly simple:
Old airplanes tend to bleed you dry on maintenance costs and fuel burn. You can also expect more delays and cancellations due to faults.
New airplanes are the opposite: Low maintenance cost, especially during the warranty period, high reliability, and low fuel burn with up to date engines, at the price of higher finance and insurance costs.
Different operators have different business models. One business case or the other will fit a particular model.
The factors with the most impact are generally fuel prices and interest rates. High prices tend to drive operators toward newer airplanes, and vice versa. On the other hand, an operator may have to go with older airplanes just because they can't finance newer ones.
Newness can be an important factor to the client. Nobody wants to ride around in a beat-up corporate jet. But these airplanes can get a new lease on life with a new interior and paint job and might be a better match for an operation especially when fuel is cheap. A renovated corporate jet will be more or less the same as a new one to the customer that doesn't know any better.
An example of the sensitivity to fuel prices from the regional airline industry. Airlines were starting to unload their CJR200s in the mid 2000s as fuel price hikes resulted in the airplane's relative inefficiency fuel burn wise making difficult to remain profitable. They were switching to newer CRJ700s and 900s. Then fuel prices crashed, and all of a sudden, used 200s could make money again thanks to a low purchase price in spite of the high fuel burn. One regional operator, Skywest airlines, started buying up every CRJ200 it could get its hands on.

For tax purposes,  a private jet used for business purposes can be written down (depreciated) to zero asset value over a certain number of years. The depreciation is deducted from your taxable income, if you have any in that tax year.
This means that depending on the skill level of your tax consultant, you can game the system to your overall benefit as long as there's some depreciated value remaining in the jet as an asset on your books. Once it's zeroed out, then you have to buy a new jet to make the game start over.
I do not know any of the details, but it boils down to a sort of tax break for high-net-worth individuals: private jet sales go up whenever the depreciation schedule on them is accelerated in the tax code.
Funeral home operators do this trick with their hearses, which can be counted on to pump a certain percentage of hearses into the used market every year. Hearse enthusiasts (I used to be one) then shop for cars in this "value dip" zone where the car has gotten retired but is not old enough to have collector value.
Note also that it may happen that the navigation systems in the jet become obsolete when the asset has been fully depreciated. Whoever buys that jet has to do a cockpit upgrade and most likely an annual before they can get it back into the air.  If this coincides with a hot-section teardown on an engine no one uses anymore, then the Lear 23 you just bought for a brief song and an uninspired dance becomes a lawn ornament.
